# Como sumar la cantidad de cada herramienta mysql

Tags: mysql

Hola buen día quisiera por favor saber si hay alguna manera en la que pueda sumar la columna "cantidad" de mi tabla "entregas_herramientas".

Adjunto una captura para mejor entendimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en la imagen tengo el id_herramienta, lo que quiero es que en "cantidad" me de la sumatoria de las herramientas que tienen el mismo id, por ejemplo la herramienta con id_herramienta 3, debería sumarse con la otra que también tiene id_herramienta 3, la columna observación no me interesa en realidad, solo necesito la sumatoria de cada herramienta en "cantidad".

Gracias de antemano la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Nos compartes por favor lo que has intentado?

Comment: Ya pude, me urgía hacerlo y no encontraba como, por eso pregunte, pero ya pude con SUM(cantidad) y GROUP BY id_herramienta, muchisimas gracias :)

Comment: Considera tu mismo responder tu pregunta y luego marcarla como aceptada, así no queda al aiare y servirá a futuros visitantes